# Unpairing paired Bluetooth Device using “removeBond” method not working in redmi android devices

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

```
This is only solution i get to *unpair* the bluetooth device but,
its not working in **xioami redmi** devices
```

> Class btClass = btDevice.getClass();
>       Method removeBondMethod = btClass.getMethod("removeBond");
>       Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) removeBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);

Answer (score 0):

From android 9 it will throw NoSuchMethodException.
"Reflection via Class.getDeclaredMethod(), Class.getMethod()    NoSuchMethodException thrown"
https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces